# Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka doesn't honor startingOffset="earliest"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I've set up Spark Structured Streaming (Spark 2.3.2) to read from Kafka (2.0.0). I'm unable to consume from the beginning of the topic if messages entered the topic before Spark streaming job is started. Is this expected behavior of Spark streaming where it ignores Kafka messages produced prior to initial run of Spark Stream job (even with .option("stratingOffsets","earliest"))?

## Steps to reproduce

1. Before starting streaming job, create `test` topic (single broker, single partition) and produce messages to the topic (3 messages in my example).
2. Start spark-shell with the following command: `spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2.3.1.0.0-78 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/`
3. Execute the spark scala code below.

```scala
// Local
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9097")
  .option("failOnDataLoss","false")
  .option("stratingOffsets","earliest")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .load()

// Sink Console
val ds = df.writeStream.format("console").queryName("Write to console")
  .trigger(org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 second"))
  .start()
```

## Expected vs actual output

I expect the stream to start from offset=1. However, it starts reading from offset=3. You can see that kafka client is actually resetting the starting offset: `2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  Fetcher:583 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 3.`

I can see that the spark stream processes messages that I produce after starting the streaming job.

Is this expected behavior of Spark streaming where it ignores Kafka messages produced prior to initial run of Spark Stream job (even with `.option("stratingOffsets","earliest")`)?

```
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  AppInfoParser:109 - Kafka version : 2.0.0.3.1.0.0-78
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  AppInfoParser:110 - Kafka commitId : 0f47b27cde30d177
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  MicroBatchExecution:54 - Starting new streaming query.
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  Metadata:273 - Cluster ID: LqofSZfjTu29BhZm6hsgsg
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:677 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9097 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:462 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:509 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  AbstractCoordinator:473 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:280 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Setting newly assigned partitions [test-0]
2019-06-18 21:22:57 INFO  Fetcher:583 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 3.
2019-06-18 21:22:58 INFO  KafkaSource:54 - Initial offsets: {"test":{"0":3}}
2019-06-18 21:22:58 INFO  Fetcher:583 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-e948eee9-3024-4f14-bcb8-75b80d43cbb1--181544888-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition test-0 to offset 3.
2019-06-18 21:22:58 INFO  MicroBatchExecution:54 - Committed offsets for batch 0. Metadata OffsetSeqMetadata(0,1560910978083,Map(spark.sql.shuffle.partitions -> 200, spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass -> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider))
2019-06-18 21:22:58 INFO  KafkaSource:54 - GetBatch called with start = None, end = {"test":{"0":3}}
```

## Spark Batch mode

I was able to confirm that batch mode reads from the beginning - so no issue with Kafka retention configuration

```scala
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9097")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .load()

df.count // Long = 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haha it was a simple typo: "stratingOffsets" should be "startingOffsets"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways. load data from kafka to streaming dataframe or load data from kafka to static dataframe(for testing).

I think you are not seeing the data because of group-id. kafka will commit the consumer group and offsets in to an internal topic. make sure the group name is unique for each read.

Here are the two options.

**Option 1: read data from kafka to streaming dataframe**

```
// spark streaming with kafka 

import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.ProcessingTime

val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","app01.app.test.net:9097,app02.app.test.net:9097")
.option("subscribe", "kafka-testing-topic")
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
.option("startingOffsets","earliest")
.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger","6000")
.load()

val ds2 = ds1.select(from_json($"value".cast(StringType), dataSchema).as("data")).select("data.*")
val ds3 = ds2.groupBy("TABLE_NAME").count()
ds3.writeStream
.trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
.queryName("query1").format("console")
.outputMode("complete")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

**Option 2: read data from kafka to static dataframe (for testing, it will load from beginning)**

```
// Subscribe to 1 topic defaults to the earliest and latest offsets
val ds1 = spark.read.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","app01.app.test.net:9097,app02.app.test.net:9097")
.option("subscribe", "kafka-testing-topic")
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
.option("spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled","false")
.load()

val ds2 = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)","topic","partition","offset","timestamp")
val ds3 = ds2.select("value").rdd.map(x => x.toString)
ds3.count()
```

Comment: I don't think `group.id` has any effect on the issue. It's transparent to API users. See the following comment from the spark doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) for `group.id` 
 "Kafka source will create a unique group id for each query automatically."

Comment: Also, if you don't specify output mode, it's using `Append` by default. You are able to use `complete` output mode because you are doing a group by (which I don't have in my example)